# How to test whether one of two values present in numpy array or matrix column on single pass?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Take a matrix like the following:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.matrix([[1,1],
               [2,0],
               [3,1],
               [5,1],
               [5,0]])
```

Then take two test values:

```
n1 = 4
n2 = 1
```

How can I test for both of them (it's guaranteed that only one if any at all will be present) and return that value? Doing two passes is simple enough:

```
if n1 in m[:, 0]:
    return n1
if n2 in m[:, 0]:
    return n2
```

What's the best numpy way to consolidate to a single look through m[:, 0]?

Comment: There's https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html, though I don't know how many passes it actually makes.

Comment: I think the best might be something like `for value in m[:,0]: if value in [n1, n2]: return value`. But I thought there might be something from numpy specifically for this. The numpy.isin shared by @user2357112 doesn't look like it would work as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you need simplicity and readability , the simplest can be found with set logic :

```
{1,4} & set(m[:,0])
```

Furthermore, the data is actually read exactly one time.

Answer (score 2):

```
m[:,0][(m[:,0] == n1) | (m[:,0] == n2)][0,0]
```

**Explanation:**

```
m = np.matrix([[1,1],
           [2,0],
           [3,1],
           [5,1],
           [5,0]])
n1 = 4; n2 = 1;
```

`(m[:,0] == n1)` returns a boolean matrix for `n1`'s existence

```
matrix([[False],
    [False],
    [False],
    [False],
    [False]], dtype=bool)
```

`(m[:,0] == n2)` returns a boolean matrix for `n2`'s existence

```
matrix([[ True],
        [False],
        [False],
        [False],
        [False]], dtype=bool)
```

Since you said that exactly a one of `n1` and `n2` parameters will be present at a time, `|`ing the above two will make the indices `True` for whatever the existing parameter.

```
(m[:,0] == n1) | (m[:,0] == n2)

matrix([[ True],
        [False],
        [False],
        [False],
        [False]], dtype=bool)
```

Indexing `m[:,0]`  by the above boolean array,

```
m[:,0][(m[:,0] == n1) | (m[:,0] == n2)]

matrix([[1]])
```

We just get the first element out of it

```
m[:,0][(m[:,0] == n1) | (m[:,0] == n2)][0,0]
1
```

**EDIT:**

After numpy 1.13 +, as @John Zwink shows, you can compact the operations up to the last one as `np.isin(m[:,0], [n1,n2])[:,0]` and then just extract the first element out of it by `np.where(np.isin(m[:,0], [n1,n2])[:,0])[0][0]`

Comment: The answer works so I don't see why this was voted down +1

Answer (score 2):

You said you want to do it in a single pass through `m`.  You can use `isin()` (in NumPy 1.13+):

```
mask = np.isin(m[:,0], [n1,n2])[:,0]
```

That gives you a boolean mask which is True where the values n1 or n2 are found.  To take the first such value:

```
row = np.where(mask)[0][0]
```

Of course, that takes a pass through `mask` which is the same length as `m`.  If you want to optimize this further, you may need to use Numba or Cython to implement a more direct solution using compiled loops.

Comment: Didn't know about `isin()`. Thanks!